# WPF ContextMenu + MenuItem memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, contextmenu, menuitem

Can anybody help with WPF and how-to free ContextMenu + MenuItem. As I’m using it, it keeps hold a WeakReference.

I have created a demo application, where it adds 10000 UserControl to a StackPanel and then removes it again. If the UserControl ContextMenu has no MenuItem, everything is fine. But if it contains a

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Properties" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Then Teleriks profiler reports 180.050 instances of WeakReference. How can I free this up?

I have googled without luck - I have read the following pages, but couldn't see any solution, else I have missed some of the informations.

[Strange wpf memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239406/strange-wpf-memory-leak)

[WPF Combobox "leaks" memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096050/wpf-combobox-leaks-memory)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa987282-6c43-4652-b712-2397d4044ff5/memoryleak-with-contextmenu-and-menuitem?forum=wpf

Demo application:

```
MainWindow.xaml has added:
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Add Empties" Click="AddClick" Margin="3" />
        <Button Content="Add With ContextMenu" Click="AddWithContextMenuClick" Margin="3" />
        <Button Content="Remove" Click="RemoveClick"  Margin="3" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="PagesStackPanel">
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel> 

MainWindow.xaml.cs has added:
private void AddClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        PagesStackPanel.Children.Add(new ChildViewEmpty());
    }
}

private void RemoveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PagesStackPanel.Children.Clear();
}

private void AddWithContextMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        PagesStackPanel.Children.Add(new ChildViewWithMenu());
    }
}

ChildViewEmpty.xaml has added: 
<Grid />

ChildViewWithMenu.xaml has added:
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Properties" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.ContextMenu>
```

Telerik profiler dump, where we can see the memory I can't free with GC, when ContextMenu has a MenuItem.
[image: Telerik profiler dump when ContextMenu has a MenuItem]

Telerik profiler dump, where ContextMenu has no MenuItem.
[image: Telerik profiler dump when ContextMenu has no MenuItem]

I’m running this on Windows 8.1 with .NET 4.5

Comment: If it is not a strong reference, why do you even care? It will not survive the next GC. Btw you can't say it is a memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, I have done multiple GC via Telerik Profiler and waited, after I have removed them again, but does release it :(

Comment: So this is neither a leak nor a problem. You can just forget about it and be happy :)

Comment: Hmm, could you please explain that a litte bit more? My problem is we an application, which can open up to +100 Pages (UserControls in TabPanels) and each Pages has +100 UserControls all with ContextMenus. I would like to free up the memory again - when we are using to much memory.

Currently I'm thing about work-around where I reuses my ContextMenu instead of creating a new for each UserControl.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could explain. You're in a automatic memory managed environment (GC). GC will take care of the memory management. You're trying to solve a problem which you really don't have. When there is a memory pressure in the machine, or some memory threshold is reached, or  GC will reclaim the memory. It is good at doing its job. You don't have to worry about. All you need to do is make sure that you don't hold any strong reference to the object (weak reference is fine). Make sure you [read it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have forced the GC via Telerik Profiler several times and via code, and waited +15min - but these references is never released :( I have tried ContextMenu.Items.Clear etc. If just have one MenuItem in a ContextMenu, then I can't get all memory released agian. And have tried add the MenuItem in xaml and codebehind - with no luck to get back to start memory usages if a ContextMenu contains a MenuItem. If the ContextMenu is empty - I have no problem getting back to start memory usage after one GC.

Comment: @CasperWollesen: Can you find which instance hold the reference to ContextMenu? I think ContextMenu is a disposable object. So, give it a name and implement IDisposable interface in your UserControl and Dispose your UserControl when it is not required. That may help.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: no, it *is* a problem. I found this question because of the same trouble. No matter how often you force the GC to reclaim memory, the MenuItems will linger on indefinitely. It's definitely a memory leak in WPF.